# java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called in view pager with Tablayout

Tags: android

I am using View pager with Tablayout in my project. I am continuously getting crash report on crashlytics. Below is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:624)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:161)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.d(ViewPager.java:1105)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.d(ViewPager.java:951)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout       
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/spice_laddooblue"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                style="@style/floating_action_button"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/spice_laddooblue"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
            </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <!--
              <View
            android:id="@+id/upper_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:visibility="visible" 
            android:layout_below = "@+id/pager"
            android:layout_above = "@+id/bannerView"/>
        -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bannerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_white_with_blue_border"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bannerText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Banner"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bannerClose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/cross_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:scrollbars="@null" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Adapter code

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    ViewPager pager;
    int count;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, ViewPager pager ) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.pager = pager;

    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return ActivityMain.setdynamicTabsNames.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        if (ActivityMain.setdynamicTabs.get(index).equalsIgnoreCase("HOME")) {
            return new FragmentIndex();
        else {
            return new FragmentDynamicTab(index);
        }
    }

        @Override
public int getCount() {
    return ActivityMain.setdynamicTabs.size();
}

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // supertabLayout.destroyItemsetupWithViewPager(container, position, objectviewPager);
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

I am setting tablayout like this in java code

```
 if (viewPager != null) {
     viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
     tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
  }
```

I have gone through all possible solutions available for this error..But none of them is working. I am unable to trace what is causing this exception.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Provide some code, how do you setup your TabLayout, at what line does it crash? This is not really helpful.

Comment: please see my edited question..I cant see where it crashes as i am not getting crash on my devices but on crashlytics i am getting this crash..

Comment: Can you add the code for adapter aswell, you are probably adding Fragments there.

Comment: Check you are not trying to set any data with `null` or `blank`

Comment: about which part of code you are talking about..

Comment: Can you post your code for `FragmentIndex`, `FragmentDynamicTab` and `ActivityMain.setdynamicTabs`?

Comment: show main activity. also

Comment: try removing @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // supertabLayout.destroyItemsetupWithViewPager(container, position, objectviewPager);
    }

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `commit()` or `commitAllowingStateLoss()` happens twice inside `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Here what I found out from android sources:

The only place from where the transaction of this adapter is commited is `FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate()` and it's `commitAllowingStateLoss()` version of `commit()`. Hence, `finishUpdate()` is called twice. This method is called from 3 places:

- `ViewPager.setAdapter();`
- `ViewPager.dataSetChanged();`
- `ViewPager.populate().`

Now, `finishUpdate()` is protected by `if (mCurTransaction != null)` check and inside this check `mCurTransaction` is nulled. Hence we cannot really commit the same transaction twice. Unless we have multiple threads working on it. `mCurTransaction` field is not volatile, which leads me to idea that you're probably calling (directly or indirectly) one of the methods listed above from the worker thread and sometimes it leads to a race condition around `mCurTransaction` field, which leads to a second `commitAllowingStateLoss()` call.

Make sure you're referencing your adapter and related objects only from main (UI) thread.

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code looks very familiar.

It looks like my project [MaterialAppBase](https://github.com/DanielShum/MaterialAppBase) in github, but this is not my code.

I read your code, if I am not being wrong, you have an activity which implements a navigation drawer at the same time, a tablayout is implemented.

This is not a good idea anyway. I see you are dealing with an app which maybe having a very complicated layout.

What you are doing is against the android design guideline, of cause against the normal UX design. You should never have two slidable view as a navigation within an activity. And the swipe gesture between NavigationDrawer and ViewPager may be conflict. Think about it, nobody does this.

However, you many have your reasons to do this. If you consist to do this, I see something wrong in your code, but i am not sure if your problem is caused by this error.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    if (ActivityMain.setdynamicTabs.get(index).equalsIgnoreCase("HOME")) {
        return new FragmentIndex();
    else {
        return new FragmentDynamicTab(index);
    }
}
```

Problem is you should not create a new fragment every time the page item renders.

What you should do is:

- You should have your fragments created in advance.
- Add your fragments in a ArrayList or something like this.
- Pass this list to the adapter and so that it can make the fragments reusable.

Look at my code [the adapter code](https://github.com/DanielShum/MaterialAppBase/blob/master/materialAppBaseLibrary/src/main/java/com/daililol/material/appbase/component/BaseFragmentPagerAdapter.java)

Comment: The example code of [using the adapter](https://github.com/DanielShum/MaterialAppBase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/daililol/material/appbase/example/ExampleTabbarActivity.java)